# Is it possible to use vscode-car-plugin in Linux to create a .car file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, wso2, maven-plugin, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I use vscode-car-plugin in my local system (Windows 10) with Visual Studio Code to develop wso2-ei projects and it works perfectly. I can generate the deployed file .car with "Build project" in Visual Studio Code or the "mvn package" in a Windows console.

The component of projects (proxies, endpoints, entries, ...) are saved in Git. For testing purpose, we implement CI/CD with Jenkins in the Linux system and the steps are:

1. Download the code from Git to Linux/path/checkout/project/src/main.
2. Generate the deployed file .car with command "mvn package"
3. Deploy the .car into WSO2-EI.

It's in the second step where we have problems because of the way to create paths of "vscode-car-plugin" which add a "\" instance of "/" and it returns the error "File not found".

[image]

If I change the /opt/jenkins/pruebas_inigof/Piloto/target/classes/main/synapse-config/local-entries**/**zzcompras_articulos.xslt.xml, the file exists.

I suppose this plugin was created for the Windows system, but I would like to use the same [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) and method to generate the .car file and avoid problems in superior environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem modifying the plugin which I downloaded from https://github.com/wso2/maven-tools/tree/master/vscode-car-plugin

I only had to add the line in the class: **CAppHandler**
[image]